# How to make a file chooser/selector in Reactjs & then print the file out

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file, react-native

I'm new to React & I'm working on a personal project using it.

I'm currently trying to implement a feature that allows the user to click a button that takes them to their file explorer & let's them select a file (just a standard file selector).

**ISSUE:**
I'm unable to find a good React package/library for this that actually makes sense. Every option I evaluated made no sense to me, and therefore I don't want to use it.

Currently I have a button that allows me to select a file, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the file's name and then print the file out?

**MY CODE:**

```
import { FilePicker } from 'react-file-picker';

MyComponent = () => (
        <FilePicker
          extensions={['.docx']}
        //   onChange={FileObject => ()}
        //   onError={errMsg => ()}
        >
          <Button style={{backgroundColor: "#f57505", width: "75px"}}>Upload</Button>
        </FilePicker>
      )
```

***Thanks!***

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the file's name

The *FileObject* return a *File* type. which means you can get the file name by doing *FileObject.name*.

> and then print the file out

You will need a third party library like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth

**Here's an working example:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FilePicker } from "react-file-picker";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import mammoth from "mammoth";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      text: ""
    };
  }

  extractWordRawText = arrayBuffer => {
    mammoth
      .extractRawText({ arrayBuffer })
      .then(result => {
        const text = result.value; // The raw text
        const messages = result.messages; // Please handle messages
        this.setState({ text });
      })
      .done();
  };

  handleFileChange = file => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = e => {
      this.extractWordRawText(e.target.result);
    };

    this.setState({ title: file.name });
  };

  render() {
    const { title, text } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <FilePicker
          extensions={["docx"]} // Notice that I removed the "."
          onChange={this.handleFileChange}
          onError={errMsg => console.log(errMsg)} // Please handle error
        >
          <button style={{ backgroundColor: "#f57505", width: "75px" }}>
            Upload
          </button>
        </FilePicker>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying that I want to get the file and then print the actual words of the file out. So if I passed in a file that said, "Hello there", I want to print out "Hello there" on my page

Comment: Ok so I see what you're saying in terms of getting the filename, but what's the actual code I'd need in order to print it on the webpage in a <h1>? I tried: FilePicker
          extensions={['.docx']}
          onChange={FileObject => (
            <div>{FileObject.name}</div>
          )}
        //   onError={errMsg => ()}
        >
          <Button style={{backgroundColor: "#f57505", width: "75px"}}>Upload</Button>
        </FilePicker>

Comment: @coder_coder123 i just edit my post with a complete working example. It extracts the raw text in a word document. I think it is a good start for your projetct. Good luck.